# Grep in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, grep

Grep in Microsoft Word?

I'd like to pull all lines with a given string from a word document. In unix world... grep does this without a glitch. Windows is less than obvious for me.

Answer (score 12):

With Cygwin (or access to a Linux machine) you could

```
antiword file.doc | grep "my phrase"
```

or

```
catdoc file.doc | grep "my phrase"
```

There are lots of command-line file format converters out there to **grep** in a similar fashion.

Purely in-Word solution could be to **Ctrl+F** (Find), and then **Find All** - however, I'm not sure if all versions of MS Word have **Find All** button.

Comment: When I saw the question title I thought "Ha! That'd be nice, wouldn't it". Never again should I underestimate GNU programmers.

Comment: The most recent version of `catdoc` segfaults on every `.doc`/`.docx` file I give it, and `antiword` just tells me my document "is not a Word Document". Do you know of any other options?

Comment: Nothing that I've used... Quick search shows that `docx2txt` exists in Debian repositories - might work. I'd also look into the OpenOffice/LibreOffice command-line format conversion utility (unoconv), which could be used for the same purpose.

Comment: @detly antiword doesn't work with .docx files, only the older MS Word formats. That's probably why it didn't recognise your document.

Answer (score 3):

I know this sounds primitive, but what's stopping you from saving the file as .txt and then ripping it apart to your liking.

Comment: Having hundreds of them to do it for, is what.

Answer (score 2):

Not got enough rep to comment but I can see this doc vs docx issue discussed so anyone chasing the thread (like I was) may find this helpful.

You do not need a special tool for docx files. docx are zipped XML files.

To extract and strip the XML try something based on

```
unzip -p "*.docx" word/document.xml | sed -e 's/<[^>]\{1,\}>//g; s/[^[:print:]]\{1,\}//g'
```

from [command line fu](http://g33kinfo.com/info/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/comfu1.txt)

Answer (score 1):

What does "line" mean in a Word context? The displayed line, which changes if you do anything to the page formatting? The paragraph? Something else?

You can do a bunch of stuff with Word's find-and-replace functions, including changing the formatting and other non-obvious things, but all of them will only act on the find-what text itself, not on any surrounding text.

Comment: grep's got that regex lovin', though!

Answer (score 1):

There is support for MS documents - Word, PowerPoint, Excel - in [CRGREP](https://sourceforge.net/projects/crgrep) which I've developed as a free opensource tool. It also greps other hard to search stuff like database tables, images, audio, archives, PDF and combinations of these. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

[PowerGREP](http://www.powergrep.com) will do [exactly that](http://www.powergrep.com/msword.html) for you, and fast - but not free. It's worth every penny, though, in my opinion. Plus, there is a 30-day free trial.

[image: Screenshot of PowerGREP searching through a Word file]

Answer (score 0):

Fast, free, open-source, and cross-platform solution: https://github.com/phiresky/ripgrep-all